# Get shipping rates in a frontend controller for particular form in magento 2.1

Tags: customer-session, checkoutsession

I am trying to get the shipping rates from the existing shipping methods enabled by the admin in my form in the frontend as the address has been entered.
**Further, I don't want to save the product in the 'quote_item' table or quote table.**

So, if there's a way to get the *shipping rates from the shipping methods enabled in the admin store* for the **product I have saved in the customer session.**